# code coverage is GREEN on the if-statement condition but RED on its expression. Why?

Tags: r, code-coverage, r-package, rstan, codecov

Here is the code coverage report (from `codecov`) for my Stan-based R package on GitHub: https://codecov.io/gh/zhengxiaoUVic/rmBayes/src/main/R/rmHDI.R

As you can see, some if-statements have green headers but red bodies. Why?

Thanks for any comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can see with the number next to the code line how often the line is called, if the line is green. In your link it is always one. The red ones on the other hand show lines where `codecov` did not have access to. You can check your test code if the body of the if statments are actually called.
e.g.: `if(!var.equal && design == "within" && method %in% 2:6)` `codecov` "visits" this line sees that it is not `TRUE`and skips everything with `{...}`

Comment: It's so weird. I have already included a `test_that()` on the content of the RED body in the if-statement, and the calculation was correct, but `codecov` just game me the RED. Also, I made a for-loop `test_that()` to test all the possible scenarios of the R function, but the percentage did not change.